# A bash script that monitors number of processes per user count all processes for each user ID with the number of processes running

Tags: linux, bash, shell, linux-kernel

[image]

The bash script is running successfully, but if you look at the second image you will that some of the count arent aligned. Any ideas why?
[image: The bash script is running succefully, but if you look at the second image you will that some of the count arent aligned. Any ideas why?]

Comment: Please don't post images of text; include the script as text, in code format, so people can copy and test it themselves without retyping. Except that you really should trim out the irrelevant bits and show just the specific problem (see ["How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). Except... this looks like expected behavior for tab characters -- they go to the next tab stop, so if start off already past the first tab stop... it's going to the second, rather than the first.

Answer (score 0):

Anything under 7 characters seems to shift one tab left.  If the char count for the process is under 7 characters add an extra tab.

Comment: I added this: if [[ ${#i} > 6 ]];  to fix it but any idea what's causing it?

Comment: Yes, the number of characters is causing it. Try typing out 5 characters in notepad, press tab twice and add a number.  Then on the next line try the same but with a 8 character word and press tab twice and see where it ends up. Its just how it lines up by the look of it.